# Isoperimetric inequalities of a group

Tags: integration, group-theory, metric-spaces, geometric-group-theory, gromov-hyperbolic-spaces

How do you transform isoperimetric inequalities of a group to the of Riemann  integrals of functions of the form $f\colon \mathbb{R}\rightarrow G$ where $G$ is a metric group so that being $\delta-$hyperbolic in the sense of Gromov is expressible via Riemann integration?

In other words, how do you define "being $\delta-$hyperbolic group" by using  integrals in metric groups?

(Note: I am not interested in the "Riemann" part, so you are free to take commutative groups with lebesgue integration etc.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this using *metric currents* in the sense of Ambrosio-Kirchheim. This is a rather new development of geometric measure theory, triggered by Gromov and really worked out only in the last decade. I should warn you that this is rather technical stuff and nothing for the faint-hearted.

Urs Lang has a set of nice lecture notes, where you can find most of the relevant references, see [here](http://www.math.ethz.ch/~lang/loc.pdf).

My friend Stefan Wenger has done quite a bit of work on Gromov hyperbolic spaces and isoperimetric inequalities, his Inventiones paper *Gromov hyperbolic spaces and the sharp isoperimetric constant* seems most relevant. You can find a link to the published paper and his other work on [his home page](http://www.math.uic.edu/~wenger/), the ArXiV-preprint is [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0609310).

---

I should add that I actually prefer to prove that a linear (or subquadratic) isoperimetric inequality implies $\delta$-hyperbolicity using a coarse notion of area (see e.g. Bridson-Haefliger's book) or using Dehn functions, the latter can be found in Bridson's beautiful paper [The geometry of the word problem](http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/bridson/papers/bfs/bfs.pdf).

Comment: Thank you Theo, I need some time to comprehend your message.

Comment: @niyazi: It is more a list of references addressing the second version of your question (and some variants) than an answer, but I think that this is the closest you can get.

Comment: The last paragraph of t.b.'s answer can be interpreted as a form of integration of functions $f:R\to X$ where $X$ is the Cayley 2-complex of a finitely presented group $G$. This is just a fancy way of saying that you compute the area of a closed curve in the Cayley graph by adding up the number of 2-cells of a disc map into the Cayley 2-complex spanned by that curve, and minimizing over all such disc maps. After all, integration is just summation.